# Getting the last known value of a variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
enter code here

fruits ={'apple':2,'banana':3,'orange':4}
money = 45
for fruit in fruits:
    print ('Each {} cost {} dollars'.format (fruit,fruits[fruit]))
    count = int(input("How many {} do you want?".format(fruit)))
    print ('You want {} {}s'.format (count,fruit))
    total = count * fruits[fruit]
    print ('The total price is {} Naira'.format(total))

    if money > total:

        print ('You have bought {} and have {} left'.format(total,money))
        money-=total
        \
        print ('Total money spent is {} and you have{}'.format(total,money))
```

If you input 2 for all the final print would be Total money spent is 8 on the last item and you have 27 for the total spent.

27 being the last known total

print ('Total money spent is {} and you have{}'.format(total,money))

This last line: I want it to print 27 at the total. How ever, it is not. It is printing the total of the last set of fruit bought which is 8.

Comment: Wouldn't the total be `2 * (2 + 3 + 4) = 18`?

Comment: Find the first subexpression that is code that you can show does what you expect extended by code that doesn't do what you expect. (Basic debugging.) If you haven't done that then you haven't done minimal debugging research. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Then extend that to a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable code (including input) with desired & actual output & clear specification & explanation. Then explain what you expect & why. Then ask 1 concise specific question about why you don't get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't sum up the totals for all fruits. When the totals are 4, 6 and 8 then "spent" is 4, 10 (4+6) and 18 (4+6+8).

```
fruits = {'apple':2, 'banana':3, 'orange':4}
money = 45
spent = 0
for fruit in fruits:
    print ('Each {} cost {} dollars'.format (fruit, fruits[fruit]))
    count = int(input("How many {} do you want?".format(fruit)))
    print ('You want {} {}s'.format (count, fruit))
    total = count * fruits[fruit]
    print ('The total price is {} Naira'.format(total))
    if money > total:
        print ('You have bought {} and have {} left'.format(total, money-total))
        money -= total
        spent += total
        print ('Total money spent is {} and you have{}'.format(spent, money))
```